# Getting error while running pytest asyncio: asyncio.queues.QueueEmpty

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, pytest, fastapi, pytest-asyncio

I am using pytest and pytest.asyncio to test discord bot (along with dpytest).
My commands are working fine but while running the test cases,  I am getting this error for few of the test cases:

> asyncio.queues.QueueEmpty

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_help(bot: commands.Bot):
    await dpytest.message("/help")
    assert dpytest.verify().message().content('Help for discord bot')
```

This is the error traceback:

```
.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/test/runner.py:112: in get_message
    message = sent_queue.get_nowait()

self = <PeekableQueue at 0x7f0d7b112850 maxsize=0 tasks=2>

    def get_nowait(self):
        """Remove and return an item from the queue.
    
        Return an item if one is immediately available, else raise QueueEmpty.
        """
        if self.empty():
>           raise QueueEmpty
E           asyncio.queues.QueueEmpty

/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/queues.py:181: QueueEmpty
```

This is the library codebase where I am redirected from this line:
dpytest.verify().message() and it is going into the except clause. Error is coming on this line:

```
message = sent_queue.get_nowait()
```

[image]
Can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: Which line triggers the actual error? And do you have a reproducible example? The problem might be outside of the code you've included.

Comment: The assert statement itself is giving the error . So when I  go inside the verify function, there it tries to access this line: message = sent_queue.get_nowait()
I have added the library codebase as well in the question